# Redirect output of a bash script to log file from config file

Tags: bash, redirect

This is the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter a filename :
read file

if [ -e $file ]
 then
if [ " -O $file" ]
 then
if [ -w $file ]
 then
  echo "Writable"
else chmod +w $file
  echo "Now writable"
  exit 0
fi
else echo File not owned by user.
     exit 0
 fi
else echo File not found.
  fi

. ./verifier.conf
```

This is it's config file

```
# The config file of verifier

# Enter the path here
verifierPath=/home/kali/test/verifier

# Redirecting file to log
exec > /tmp/verifier.log
```

I want to redirect stdout and stderr of the script to a log file in /tmp by making changes in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
exec > >(tee "/tmp/verifier.log") 2>&1
```

Comment: Tried it.Not working.The log file is still empty after running the script.